# Get the correct key on a multidimensioanl array search with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to get this working for the past day, with no luck. Finally, I did it with a bad hack and would like how to do it right.

I need to find the key for a search on an array with the following structure

```
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total] => 52
                    [date] => 2017-02-08
                    [nickname] => AAAA
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [total] => 53
                    [date] => 2017-02-09
                    [nickname] => AAAA
                )


        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [8] => Array
                (
                    [total] => 11
                    [date] => 2017-02-08
                    [nickname] => XXXX
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [total] => 14
                    [date] => 2017-02-09
                    [nickname] => XXXX
                )


        )

)
```

I need to search by date for each array inside the array, for that I am using the following code

```
$key = array_search($value, array_column($sales, 'date'));
```

Which goes inside a `foreach` looping the big array.

The *problem* I have is that `$key` instead of returning me the id it seems to be returning me the position. So for example for `$value = '2017-02-09'` it will always return me `1` instead of `1` and `9`

Is it just that I don't understand how array_seach works or is there any way I can get `1` and `9` as a result of the search inside the `foreach`

Any tip in the right direction will be appreciated,

Comment: I suppose, for your example `$key` should be an array as there are two dates with same value `2017-02-09`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested loop to append all the keys that match your date value to an array.

```
foreach ($your_array as $set) {
    foreach ($set as $key => $item) {
        if ($item['date'] == $value) $keys[] = $key;
    }
}
```

For your example array, this would result in `$keys = [1, 9]`.

Answer (score 1):

> **array_search** — Searches the array for a given value and returns **the
>   first corresponding key** if successful

The solution using [**The RecursiveIteratorIterator class**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) :

```
$keys = [];
$value = '2017-02-09';
$it = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveArrayIterator($data), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ($it as $k => $v) {
    if (is_array($v) && isset($v['date']) && $v['date'] == $value) {
        $keys[] = $k;
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns the first corresponding key, but I am calling it inside a foreach, so I expect to be 1 and 9 respectively, but I always get 1 and 1.